# swapping the column value of 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

Hi I have 2 tables `tab1` and `tab2`. I want to replace `id` column of `tab1` by `id` column of `tab2`. Can I do it in single `select` query?

Input:

```
Tab1
id  name
101  AA
102  BB
102  CC

Tab2
id  Name
11   XX
12   YY
13   ZZ
```

Output should be

```
Tab1
id  Name
11   AA
12   BB
13   CC

Tab2
id  name
101  XX
102  YY
103  ZZ
```

Thanks
 Onkar

Comment: How do you know which record from `tab1` goes to which record in `tab2`?  What is the relationship for `ordering`?  Once you have that determined, then you can use a `row_number` approach with `joins` to update accordingly (although you'll probably also need a temp table to store the original values).

Comment: Seems odd... but how do you decide which ID goes with which name, or which IDs are swapped with each other? Just numerically? And are they all really so closely related (so e.g. could just add/remove the zero in the middle)? Are either (or both) IDs PKs or FKs?

Comment: Actually this question was asked in interview. Even I don't know how in real world application it is required.

Comment: `select` queries do not change data.  And `select` queries only return one result set.  Your data suggests that you want two result sets from a single select.  Hence, it does not seem possible with a single `select`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the last row of Tab2 is `102, 'ZZ'` or `103, 'ZZ'`(i.e. id is distinct and ordered).

If that's `103, 'ZZ'`, then the following query works :

```
select decode(sign(max(ascii(name))-77),-1, min(id), max(id)) id, name
  from
( 
select t1.id, t1.dr, t2.name from
(
  select id, dense_rank() over (order by id) dr from Tab1
  union all
  select id, dense_rank() over (order by id) dr from Tab2
) t1
 join
(
  select name, dense_rank() over (order by id) dr from Tab1
  union all
  select name, dense_rank() over (order by id) dr from Tab2
) t2 on ( t1.dr = t2.dr )
)
group by name;
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e59a8/1)

Comment: Yes it is 103. Thanks @Barbaros